# How to make my form background transparent in my WINCE 6.0 Application

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I am trying to develop an WinCE Device Application. I need to set the form transparency or opacity. But not sure how to set that. I tried to overide onPaint and OnPaintBackground using transparent image but couldn't succeed. Any Suggestion welcomes

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it's not possible to simply set a property to have a transparent effect.  You can however paint the background of your form with an image, and similarly for custom controls you add.  Here are some articles to inspire you, http://alphamobilecontrols.codeplex.com/, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/TransparentControl.aspx. There are also 3rd party controls you can use which have such features included.  This one comes to mind http://beemobile4.net/products/ipack just because I saw it cited on stack, but do not infer this as an endorsement.